# PKCS11: CKA_VALUE_LEN attribute and Unwrap key

Tags: aes, pkcs11, key-wrap

In PKCS11 specification v2.40, we see some confusion with `CKA_VALUE_LEN` attribute and `UnwrapKey` behavior.

From PKCS11 spec 2.40 section 2.8.2,

[image]

2 -> MUST not be specified when object is created with `C_CreateObject`.

3 -> MUST be specified when object is generated with `C_GenerateKey` or `C_GenerateKeyPair`.

6 -> MUST not be specified when object is unwrapped with `C_UnwrapKey`.

In the AES-ECB and AES-CBC, spec tells to pass `CKA_VALUE_LEN` (section 2.8.4),

[image]

So what is expected from application? Do the applications need to pass `CKA_VALUE_LEN` during unwrap?

NOTE: Even PKCS11 spec 3.0 is also saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think that's sufficiently unclear to ask for clarification of the authors of the document, and it probably needs fixing.

However, what I do know is that the key size is definitely clear from the wrapped key itself. So there is definitely no need to specify `CKA_VALUE_LEN` during the call to `C_UnwrapKey`. There is no need to check it either; I'd be more worried about the *value* of the key then the size of the key if the key can be altered somehow.

What is possibly meant is that the key size of the wrapped key is determined using `CKA_VALUE_LEN` **during key generation**. Because in that case the *type by itself* doesn't specify the output length, i.e. the size of the key being unwrapped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is for AES-ECB/AES-CBC(no pad), in case of C_Wrap  spec says to do zero pad for non-blocked size. If zero padding is done in wrap, in unwrap we must know the size of the key, otherwise we don't know whether the data is zero padded or data itself has zero data at the end. Just pointing the spec section 2.8.4, "For wrapping, the mechanism encrypts the value of the CKA_VALUE attribute of the key that is wrapped, padded on the trailing end with up to block size minus one null bytes so that the resulting length is a multiple of the block size."

Comment: Hmm, oh yeah, I forgot about the zero padding. For some keys that may indeed be a problem. In the case of public / private keys the application can establish this from context (ASN.1 DER). So in that case I'd just supply the length with symmetric keys 'cause they are unstructured.